# Groovy / Mocking Sql

Tags: unit-testing, testing, groovy, mocking, spock

I'm trying to mock the Sql instance in Groovy the following way, I'm using the spock framework for testing. However the test fails, please see below:

```
class SQLStatsStorageManagerTest extends Specification {
    def mockSql

    def setup() {

        mockSql = GroovyMock(Sql, global: true)
    }

    void "SQLStatsStorageManager instantiation succeed"() {
        def c

        when: "SQLStatsStorageManager is instantiated"
            c = new SQLStatsStorageManager("test", [hostname: "localhost", port: 666, database: "db", login: "root", password: "pass"])

        then: "there is no error and name is set"
            1 * mockSql.newInstance('jdbc:mysql://localhost:666/db', 'root', 'pass', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
            assert c.getName() == "test"
    }
}
```

The test fails with the following error:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * mockSql.newInstance('jdbc:mysql://localhost:666/db', 'root', 'pass', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * mockSql.newInstance(jdbc:mysql://localhost:666/db, 'root', 'pass', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
```

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that in unmatched invocation `jdbc:mysql://localhost:666/db` is not a `String`, `Url` maybe? I guess that this is the part that doesn't match (there's a single apostrophe missing).

Comment: If you found my answer useful please accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the fact that the only argument that does not match is db link.

You try to verify it as an instance of `String`:

```
'jdbc:mysql://localhost:666/db'
```

but in unmatched invocation it is:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:666/db
```

so here's the question, what it actually is? Verify the types and you'll have the problem solved.